# Laravel roles with laravel-permission

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, permissions

I am using the [laravel-permission](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission) package. I've created 2 roles, `admin` and `user`, and associated the `admin` role with a permission `Access CMS`. I've also created two users, one with the `admin` role and one with the `user` role.

I've put all my `admin` routes behind `AdminMiddleware`:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => ['auth', 'isAdmin']], function() {
  // Routes
}
```

The middleware comes from [this tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/user-authorization-in-laravel-54-with-spatie-laravel-permission):

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (!Auth::user()->hasPermissionTo('Access CMS')) {
        die('aargh');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

This works with the user with the `admin` role. The problem is that when I log in with the other user, it `die`s (as it should) but the user remains logged in. I.e. if I echo out the `Auth::user()` after this attempt it shows the non-`admin` user. What I am expecting is that it prevents that user being logged in at all. What am I missing?

Comment: Why do you want to log the user auth if he does not have permission to that route? IMO it would be more logical redirect this user to a certain page and show an error that he does not have access: `return redirect()->route('home')->withErrors['No access']`

Comment: My point is that by the time it hits that middleware the user is already logged in. If I put that `return` statement in the middleware the user would still be logged in.

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the best option but you could try.

`Auth::logout();`

Then return the user to home once they have been logged out.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing that the `auth` middleware is executed first. Middlewares are executed in the order that they're declared in the array.
[routing groups](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#route-groups)

To achieve not logging in at all, you will have to change the order of the middlewares, but you would not be able to use `Auth::user()` anymore since the user would not be authed. So to do this without `Auth::user()` you would have to query the database yourself to find the user object and then check the permission. This is not recommended though. Why does it matter at all whether the user is authed?

Comment: Why is it not recommended to find the user object and then check the permission? How else could I check the permission?